# Generic type javascript for parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, generics, inheritance

I want to have a extendable parent class with generic type, in java it looks like this

```
public class Parent<T> {
   private T t;

   public T get() {
      return t;
   }
...
```

And the child should've looks like this

```
public class Child extend Parent<Object> {
    ...
```

How do i accomplish this in javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
export default class Hotel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
}
```

then `Hotel` class extends Component class of React

Comment: Where's the generic type?